# mysql: How to get next date of the selected day?

Tags: mysql

My problem is, I have a form named 'weekly-off setting' in which I am selecting a one or two days as a weekly off.If I have weekly off on saturday then I want to find out the first saturdays date which is coming in the first week of the selected month.So can anyone tell me the mysql query for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify?  How is this related to MYSQL.  Is there a table with values that you are trying to select from - how does the "weekly-off-setting" fit into that table, and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: See some examples [here](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/99-Finding-Next-Monday-using-MySQL-Dates.html)

Comment: It will be better to do in the language in you which having form. Do you really have form in mysql?

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear from your statement, but you're trying to find the next Saturday?

```
select date_add(now(), interval 7-dayofweek(now()) day);
```

Which unfortunately will return *today* if you're on a Saturday, so the sequence becomes:

```
SET @OFFSET = 7-dayofweek(now());
SET @OFFSET = IF(@OFFSET = 0, 7, @OFFSET);
select date_add(now(), interval @OFFSET day);
```

which can be combined into one:

```
select date_add(now(), interval IF(7-dayofweek(now()) = 0, 7, 7-dayofweek(now())) day) as next;
```