# Running a Query for Between Monday and Sunday in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

We currently have an issue where we are running a query to count the amount of leads our clients have between certain dates. Some of our clients have a limit of how many leads they can receive in a week. For example a client of ours has a Weekly Limit of 6. We run our leads from a Monday (start of the week) to a Sunday (being the end of the week).

We have noticed that our client in the example has received 9 leads for last week. He received all of his 6 leads on the Monday (27th June) and then 3 more on the Sunday (3rd July). Really, it should have only been 6. This is our code below: -

```
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("monday this week"));
$sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 day",strtotime("monday this week")));
```

This is part of our SQL query: -

```
AND (a.overall_weekly > (SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS countId FROM company_referrals c, referrals r WHERE r.id = c.referral_id AND c.company_id = a.id AND r.date >= '".$monday." 00:00:00' AND r.date <= '".$sunday." 23:59:59' AND c.successful = 1) OR a.overall_weekly = '-1')
```

If anybody has any idea how we could overcome this that would be great. I think I'm just having a dumb moment!

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: strtotime is neat, but it's not infallible. make sure that "monday this week" actually works in all of your usage cases.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for getting back to me. It does work but there seems to be an issue when we actually get to Sunday. Is there a way that Sunday could be interpreted as a start of the week over a monday?

Comment: this'll probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338087/mysql-how-to-get-next-date-of-the-selected-day   don't do the date math in php, and definitely not with strtotime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting as answer since it won't fit into a comment.

Running this on Monday, Jul 4th:

```
<?php

$now = time();
echo "Currently: ", date('r', $now), "\n";
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        echo "i:$i\t ", date('r', strtotime("monday this week", $now + ($i * 86400))), "\n";
}
```

gives

```
$ php z.php
Currently: Mon, 04 Jul 2016 13:39:55 -0500
i:0      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:1      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:2      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:3      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:4      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:5      Mon, 04 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
i:6      Mon, 11 Jul 2016 00:00:00 -0500
```

Note how on day 6 (Sunday), "next week" has kicked in, and you get the Jul 11th, not the 4th.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for showing me this. How would I replicate this into my code for my query?